# My question is about the structure ''is + learn'' in the sentence

Tags: grammar, word-choice, tense, sentence-structure

I saw the structure ''is + learn'' in a sentence in a book but I wonder whether it is correct. Please see the original sentence as: '' When something is inevitable, all you can do is learn to accept it and try to be at peace with it''.

Comment: "All you can do is [verb]" is a perfectly normal sentence construction, meaning "[Doing that] is your only option."

Answer (score 1):

Idiomatically, we rarely include the infinitive marker in contexts like *All you can do is [**to**] be polite*. Feasibly, including it is actually "ungrammatical", but I don't really know or care about that. Suffice it to say *It's not good, [**but it does occur**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22all+you+can+do+is+to+be%22)* (that's a link to many written instances in Google Books).

On the other hand, we ***did*** normally used to include the infinitive marker in very similar contexts like *What you need to do is **to be** polite* - because of [***parallelism***.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelism_(grammar)) But as implied by this usage chart, in recent decades people have [started preferring brevity over parallelism...](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to%20do%20is%20be%2Cto%20do%20is%20to%20be&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3)

[image]